# Muidatatable checkbox is not working fine when i pass SetState in OnRowSelectionCHange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have following options in MuiDataTable its working fine but when i am passing setSelectedItems() state checkbox is not working

```
const option: FilterType | any = {
        filterType: 'checkbox',
        
        download: false,
        expandableRowsOnClick: false,
        search: false,
        selectableRows:'multiple',
        selectableRowsHeader:true ,
        selectToolbarPlacement: 'none',
        onRowSelectionChange: (currentSelect:any, allSelected:any) => {           
            const result = allSelected.map((item:any) => { return data.at(item.index) });
            const selectedIds = result.map((item:any) => {
                 return item.order_id;
            }); 
            setSelectedItems(()=>[...selectedItems,...selectedIds])
            console.log(selectedIds);           
        },
}
```

Can someone guide me how to resolve this issue?